# How can I convert a string to a float without losing trailing 0s in Java?

Tags: java, string, floating-point, type-conversion

Usually when converting a string to a float you lose decimal trailing 0s.
For specific reasons I need to keep exactly the number of trailing 0s I have in the string.
The code I currently use for this is

```
float res = Float.parseFloat(avgStr);
```

but this method removes trailing 0s. is there a better way to do this?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to do with those zeros? If you want to print it, You can use `System.out.printf("%.10f",float_data);` which prints exact `10` digits after floating point. Even if there is no digits left, It prints `0` there.

Comment: You are correct, floats don't store trailing zeros, so if you care about what the string looks like, you need to check the string before you convert it.

Comment: Technically the 0s are stored, the number is expressed in the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format. If you don't need to do calculations with the string don't convert it.

Comment: Anyone care to answer?

Comment: i need to maintain a very specific amount of decimals to avoid complications further down the line

Comment: Please just explain why you need the trailing zeros. You will get much better help if you actually explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Are you sure you should be using float rather than BigDecimal? A BigDecimal has a scale factor that records the number of digits after the decimal point. Just being a decimal, rather than binary, format makes it more suitable for anything where decimal places matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
float res = Float.parseFloat(avgStr);
System.out.printf("%.2f", res);
```

With the "%.2f", it'll display 2 decimal places without loosing the trailing 0s. 
Or you  can try this example:

```
String st = "12.0000";
float dd = Float.valueOf(st);
int len = st.substring(st.indexOf(".") + 1, st.length()).length();
System.out.printf("%." + len + "f", dd);
```

If you want to get an accurate decimal places of the string you want to convert to the data type float. :)